# Set Column value Order RDLC

Tags: c#, sql, rdlc

I am fetching data using `order by Case` example :

```
Select * from subject order by  CASE Subject.Title
                      WHEN 'English' THEN 1
                      WHEN 'Urdu' THEN 2
                      WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN 3
                      WHEN 'Science' THEN 4
```

When I display this data on RDLC Report, it doesn't set order of column.

Comment: does output shows correct in SSMS ?

Comment: Yes dataset show correct order...but it doesnt show exact order as in Dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your query.
In your report designer you have to use the `Sorting Tab` as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251728%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Good luck.

Comment: can u give me expression how to sort them in custom way

Comment: Please elaborate more on your situation. Are you using a designer? Are you trying to access it by code?

Comment: In my Report Designer it shows Subjects Columns with  Marks...now i have requirement to order the Subject Name by Custom Such as English Subject Column should be at first then Urdu Subject at 2nd and 3 wud be Math....i just want to order them my subject colunm

Comment: You need to get to the properties page.  Are you using a table control?

Comment: Can i use any expression for Subject column to display subjects Name custom order ??

Comment: Yes i m using table for deisgner

Comment: Right-click the column and select properties. You can see a more thorough example [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1561949.aspx?what+are+my+options+for+sorting+an+rdlc)

Comment: Nope thats not helping...m asking if there any expression to order by the set of column exactly same which query fetched

Comment: If you sort by that same column the order should stay the same.  One more thing you can try is edit the RDLC file in notepad and remove the element named `SortExpression`

Comment: Thank you so much Adamit !! It worked ... I opened my rdlc in notepad and removed sort expression now it showing same order in which query fetch

Comment: I'm glad it did :)   Please accept the answer if you deem it worthy :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Select * from subject order by  CASE 
                  WHEN Subject.Title = 'English' THEN '1'
                  WHEN Subject.Title = 'Urdu' THEN '2'
                  WHEN Subject.Title = 'Mathematics' THEN '3'
                  WHEN Subject.Title = 'Science' THEN '4'
```

Comment: can you explain how this will help OP?